# Add new column to data frame and populate the row with value from a certain logic

Tags: r, dataframe

I need to add a column to a data frame and based from certain condition of the existing columns to populate the value of the newly added column

Sample data frame :

```
 DeptID     Name    Age    Active 
  2        Aira     23      0        
  2        Ben      25      1        
  2        Cat      32      1
  3        Dan      28      1
```

Desired output : if DeptID = 2 then (if Active = 1 then Rate = 0 else Rate = 1) else Rate is empty

```
DeptID     Name     Age    Active    Rate
  2        Aira     23      0        0    
  2        Ben      25      1        1
  2        Cat      32      1        1
  3        Dan      28      1
```

I have try below code, but always got 0, please help.

```
data = cbind(data, Rate=sapply(data$DeptID, function(x) {
   ifelse(as.character(x) %in% c(2), ifelse(as.character(data$Active) %in% c(1),1,0),0)
 }))
```

Comment: Your desired output seems at odds with the stated conditions. You say if `Active == 1`, `Rate == 0`, which is not what your desired output shows. My Answer gives the output suggested by the conditions, not the supplied output. It's trivial to fix, but I thought I'd ask you to clarify what you want first.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are on the right track with `ifelse` but you can do this without splitting on `DeptID`:

```
dat <- transform(dat, Rate = ifelse(DeptID == 2, ifelse(Active == 1, 0, 1), ""))
dat

> dat
  DeptID Name Age Active Rate
1      2 Aira  23      0    1
2      2  Ben  25      1    0
3      2  Cat  32      1    0
4      3  Dan  28      1
```

You could also do these things via indexing to replace elements in the data frame (starting with your original data in `dat` again)

```
dat$Rate <- "" ## add in one of the options as a default value for column
dat$Rate[dat$DeptID == 2 & dat$Active == 1] <- 0
dat$Rate[dat$DeptID == 2 & dat$Active == 0] <- 1

> dat
  DeptID Name Age Active Rate
1      2 Aira  23      0    1
2      2  Ben  25      1    0
3      2  Cat  32      1    0
4      3  Dan  28      1
```

Comment: Hi Gavin. Is it possible to write:
dat$Rate <- ifelse(DeptID == 2, ifelse(Active == 1, 0, 1), "")
? Am I wrong?

Comment: @FraNut Why don't you try it? But yes, you are wrong; R won't be able to find `DeptID` and `Active`; you need to preface those with `dat$` as in `dat$Rate <- ifelse(dat$DeptID == 2, ifelse(dat$Active == 1, 0, 1), "")`. Which was why I used `transform()`, which allows one to do this without prefacing everything.